# Instagram Web scraping followers

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

I am trying to extract the followers of a random web page in Instagram. I tried to use python in combination with Beautiful Soup.

Nonetheless I have not received any information at web page where I could access

```
def get_user_info( user_name):
    url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + user_name + "/?__a=1"
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print ('Seems like dns lookup failed..')
        time.sleep(60)
        return None
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print ('User: ' + user_name + ' status code: ' + str(r.status_code))
        print (r)
        return None
    info = json.loads(r.text)
    return info['user']

get_user_info("wernergruener")
```

As mentioned I do not get the followers of the page. How could I do this?

Cheers,
Andi

Comment: I've tried searching instagram for 'wernergruener' and come up empty. Is that the exact name?

Answer (score 0):

**With API/JSON:**

I'm not familiar with the Instagram API, but it doesn't look like it returns detailed information about a person's followers, just the number of followers.

You should be able to get that information using `info["user"]["followed_by"]["count"]`.

**With raw page/Beautiful Soup:**

Assuming the non-API page reveals the information you want about a person's followers, you'll want to download the raw HTML (instead of JSON) and parse it using Beautiful Soup.

```
def get_user_info( user_name):
    url = "https://www.instagram.com/" + user_name
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print ('Seems like dns lookup failed..')
        time.sleep(60)
        return None
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print ('User: ' + user_name + ' status code: ' + str(r.status_code))
        print (r)
        return None
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    # find things using Beautiful Soup

get_user_info("wernergruener")
```

Beautiful Soup has some of the most intuitive documentation I've ever read. I'd start there:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

**With API/python-instagram:**

Other people have already done a lot of the heavy lifting for you. I think [python-instagram](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram) should offer you easier access to the information you want.